# Pycharm - package pywinauto is not listed in project requirements

Tags: pycharm

I downloaded pywinauto using PIP, I imported it.
but I've got an message like below.
I updated up-to-date but it doesn't disappeared.
How should I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you run `python` in `cmd.exe` and execute `import pywinauto; print(pywinauto.__version__)`? What is the content of `requirements.txt`?

Comment: pywinauto  version is 0.6.0

Comment: Where can I find requirements.txt?

Comment: Probably in the root folder of your project.

Answer (score 5):

You can fix this error by creating a `requirements.txt` at the root folder of your project.

Your `requirements.txt` file should look something like this (with your packages).

```
python-xlib==0.19
pywinauto==0.6.3
```

You can generate this using your current python environment with:

```
# Freeze all packages into requirements.txt
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Once you've generated your `requirements.txt`, you need to set the path in PyCharm.

Open `Preferences` > `Tools` > `Python Integrated Tools`.
Select your `requirements.txt` file under `Package requirements file`.